# Add path in network

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I've this expression:

```
MATCH (g:GNE{sym:"ST1"})-[:like]->(c:CLUSTER)<-[:Belong]-(h:GNE) 
WITH h, COUNT(c) AS score, COLLECT(c.clusterInfo) AS info
ORDER BY score DESC
WHERE score >= 4
RETURN h.sym, score, info, h.chr
```

So, I would like ADD MORE the follow pattern, like this sentence:

```
(c:CLUSTER)-[:has]-(v:ORTH) where v.Term are equal in all CLUSTER
```

Any suggestions? 
Thanks!

Comment: it would be great if you could set up a [graph-gist](http://gist.neo4j.org) seeded with some data, as I've seen that you've asked multiple questions in this domain. So it would be easier for others to follow along and reason about your model. And it would be cool to have anyway :)

Comment: Is this to act as a filter? i.e only return me results where v.term is equal in all the collected clusters? is the value that v.term needs to be equal to a parameter of the query?

Answer (score 1):

To filter the results by an additional parameter:

```
MATCH (g:GNE{sym:"ST1"})-[:like]->(c:CLUSTER)<-[:Belong]-(h:GNE) 
WITH h, c
MATCH (c:CLUSTER)-[:has]-(v:ORTH{term:"Your Value"})
WITH h, COUNT(c) AS score, COLLECT(c.clusterInfo) AS info
ORDER BY score DESC
WHERE score >= 4
RETURN h.sym, score, info, h.chr
```

If you literally want all the values for v.term to be the same (but you do not know what that value is ahead of time) then it's a bit more involved and I think that you will have to use the WHERE ALL collection predicate to  compare the term property in a collection of ORTH nodes.

```
MATCH (g:GNE{sym:"ST1"})-[:like]->(c:CLUSTER)<-[:Belong]-(h:GNE) 
WITH h, c
MATCH (c:CLUSTER)-[:has]-(v:ORTH)
WITH h, COUNT(c) AS score, COLLECT(c.clusterInfo) AS info, COLLECT(v) as orths
ORDER BY score DESC
WHERE ALL(orth IN TAIL(orths) WHERE (orth.term = HEAD(orths).term))
AND score >= 4
RETURN h.sym, score, info, h.chr
```

If that is what you want it may be faster to break the HEAD and TAIL collection modifiers into a separate WITH and apply the length filter first:

```
MATCH (g:GNE{sym:"ST1"})-[:like]->(c:CLUSTER)<-[:Belong]-(h:GNE) 
WITH h, c
MATCH (c:CLUSTER)-[:has]-(v:ORTH)
WITH h, COUNT(c) AS score, COLLECT(c.clusterInfo) AS info, COLLECT(v) as orths
WHERE score >= 4
WITH h, score, info, TAIL(orths) as orhttail, HEAD(orths) as orthhead
WHERE ALL(orth IN orthtail WHERE (orth.term = orthead.term))
RETURN h.sym, score, info, h.chr
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an untested suggestion.

```
MATCH (g:GNE{sym:"ST1"})-[:like]->(c:CLUSTER)<-[:Belong]-(h:GNE) 
WITH h, c
MATCH (c:CLUSTER)-[:has]-(v:ORTH)
WITH v, h, COUNT(c) AS score, COLLECT(c.clusterInfo) AS info
WHERE v.Term are equal in all CLUSTER
ORDER BY score DESC
WHERE score >= 4
RETURN h.sym, score, info, h.chr
```

Alternatively:

```
MATCH (g:GNE{sym:"ST1"})-[:like]->(c:CLUSTER)  // Find 'c', we don't need 'g' after this
WITH c
MATCH (v:ORTH)-[:has]-(c:CLUSTER)<-[:Belong]-(h:GNE) // From 'c', find the datums of interest
WITH v, h, COUNT(c) AS score, COLLECT(c.clusterInfo) AS info
WHERE v.Term are equal in all CLUSTER
ORDER BY score DESC
WHERE score >= 4
RETURN h.sym, score, info, h.chr
```

Comment: What does `WHERE v.Term are equal in all CLUSTER` do?

Comment: I have no idea. It is the specific `WHERE` clause mentioned in the OP

Comment: Oh I see, you mean that's not syntax. Apologies. I assumed it was some obscure collections type Cypher syntax, given that it was formatted as code in the original question. If it's pseudo-code, then I have to admit I don't fully understand what intention it is attempting to show.